# Switch between numbers and symbols on caps lock

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

Is it possible to set caps lock to switch between inserting numbers and the symbols they normally trigger when one holds shift?

e.g. when you normally press the 9 key, you get a `(` unless caps lock is on.

I tried adding this line to my layout file, on `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`:

```
key <AE05> {        [ percent, 5 ]       };
```

This effectively switches the 'normal' and 'shift' meanings, but it won't work on caps lock - only on shift.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:shiftlock
```

Comment: Well, I tried and this would make EVERY KEY in the keyboard work differently, as if you are pressing Shift all the time. Like arrow keys will output like shift+arrow, you cannot scroll up/down with mouse wheel, Ctrl+n will be like Ctrl+N, in terminal Delete will enter `2~` and so on. If you only want it for upper line number/symbols, I will say it is overkill.