# What is the Mode_switch modifier for?

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap, special-characters

Playing with [`xmodmap`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xmodmap) I encountered a modifier key I hadn't heard of: [`Mode_switch`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=Mode_switch). It seems to have something to do with inserting special characters.

I assigned it to a key but it seems to have no effect. What is it for? Is it different from [`ISO_Level3_Shift` (Alt Gr)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=ISO_Level3_Shift)?

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249122/why-do-my-xmodmap-binds-involving-altgr-only-work-on-some-keys/313711#313711

Comment: Linking in a related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461972/why-tab-cant-be-modified-with-iso-level3-shift

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`Mode_switch` is the old-style (pre-XKB) name of the key that is called <kbd>AltGr</kbd> on many keyboard layouts. It is similar to <kbd>Shift</kbd>, in that when you press a key that corresponds to a character, you get a different character if <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is also pressed. Unlike `Shift`, `Mod_switch` is not a modifier in the X11 sense because it normally applies to characters, not to function keys, so applications only need to perform a character lookup to obtain the desired effect.

`ISO_Level3_Shift` is the XKB version of this key. Generally speaking, XKB is a lot more complicated and can do some extra fancy stuff. XKB's mechanism is more general as it allows keyboard layouts to vary in which keys are influenced by which modifiers, it generalizes sticky (<kbd>CapsLock</kbd>-style) and simultaneous-press (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-style) modifiers and so on.

Comment: Great to know that `ISO_Level3_Shift` can act 'stickily', I was looking for that functionality for a long while: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39014/switch-between-numbers-and-symbols-on-caps-lock

Comment: @Gilles So, are `AltGr` and `Mode_switch` the same keys? If not, in this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices), they sound as if they are the same things. Could you clarify this a bit?

Comment: @Utku `Mode_switch` and `ISO_Level3_Shift` do the same thing in slightly different ways. I don't claim to understand the differences; most of the time they don't matter but I do remember that mixing xmodmap with XKB names occasionally caused modifiers not to work right.

Comment: @Gilles I also don't understand the differences but I'm ending up either with `us(cz_sk_de)` features or with custom xmodmap mappings for some keys (comma for example) depending on whether `AltGr` is `Mode_switch` or `ISO_Level3_Shift` but can't get both features at the same time.

Comment: Sticky keys are not `CapsLock`-style. Sticky keys are called “latch” and lock-keys are called locks.  Sticky keys are released after the next non-modifier is pressed while lock keys are in effect until they are pressed again.

Answer (score 21):

This answer is not meant to contradict @Gilles' answer, but is meant to describe another aspect of [xkb](/questions/tagged/xkb) Input handling which I feel is "under-illuminated" in his answer.

You can use both `ISO_Level3_Shift`(Alt-Gr) and `Mode_switch` at the same time **with different results**. It requires some configuration, but you can have them both, and use them to produce **6** different keys per physical keyboard key!

You can e.g. configure <kbd>Tab</kbd> to be `Mode_switch` when held with [xcape](/questions/tagged/xcape) [⌂](https://github.com/alols/xcape) and [xmodmap](/questions/tagged/xmodmap), then e.g. the key labeled "H" on the keyboard could produce following characters/keys:

<kbd><kbd>h</kbd>
<kbd>H</kbd>
<kbd>← (Cursor)</kbd>
<kbd>← (Symbol)</kbd>
<kbd>┘</kbd>
<kbd>┐</kbd></kbd>
 <kbd>with <kbd>H</kbd>

with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>

with <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>

with <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>

with <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>

with <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd></kbd>

So, to come back around to your question: `IL3S` and `Mode_switch` can be configured to mean different things, so you can have cursor keys and **~200 useful characters** from the (accented) languages, box-drawing, and technical character set on the **35 keys** of the 3 letter rows.

To accomplish the above:

```
# Initial Setup
xmodmap -e 'keycode 23 = Mode_switch ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab'
xmodmap -e 'keycode any = Tab'
xcape -e "Mode_switch=Tab"
```

example for <kbd>H</kbd>:

```
xmodmap -pke | grep 'h H'
# Make note of the keycode, note the 8 columns after the `=`,
# then edit and feed back into xmodmap with:
xmodmap -e 'keycode  43 = h H lowrightcorner uprightcorner Left leftarrow h H'
```

Comment: Wow! I see what you mean in your 2nd last paragraph now, you just made my day  I no longer need to copy and paste from [htmlarrows.com](http://htmlarrows.com/) to write things like `fn: A → B`.

Comment: I think the normal way of doing this is by using `ISO_Level5_Shift`.  This produces 8 levels, the 7th being `lvl3+lvl5+H` &c.

Answer (score 6):

`Mode_shift` in Xkb is a shift key for groups or layouts.  If you have a
layout with multiple groups, you can hold down this key to access the
next group.  If you have several layouts, you can hold down this key to
shift between layouts (†1).

So `Mode_shift` is to groups what <kbd>Shift</kbd> (or `Shift_L` and
`Shift_R`, to use the keysym names) is to levels.

This might become more clear if we consider that `Mode_shift` has an
alias called `ISO_Group_Shift` (†2).  There are also keys called
`ISO_Group_Latch` and `ISO_Group_Lock` which correspond to
`ISO_Level2_Latch` (latch shift) and `Shift_Lock`, respectively (†3).

There are also a number of aliases for different scripts:

- `kana_switch`
- `Arabic_switch`
- `Greek_switch`
- `Hebrew_switch`
- `Hangul_switch`

†1: This is based on my understanding of Xkb’s “groups” and “layouts”.
It seems that they are treated the same as far as selecting between them
with keys like this.

†2: I am basing this on the file `keysymdef.h` in [this Git repository](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/x11proto)
at revision ab8666661fc6 (“Add XF86XK_AudioPreset”, 2017-05-10).  On
installations you will probably find this file at
`/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h`.

†3: There is also a key [`ISO_Lock`](https://web.archive.org/web/20020202090345/http://www.tsu.ru/~pascal/en/xkb/gram-action.html#iso-lock), a kind of general-purpose lock key.

## The meaning of the `AltGr` key

Gilles mentioned in [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55154/185805) the connection with the
<kbd>AltGr</kbd> key:

> `Mode_switch` is the old-style (pre-XKB) name of the key that is
>   called <kbd>AltGr</kbd> on many keyboard layouts.

That lead me to suspect that “AltGr” might stand for
“alternate/alternative group”, since `Mode_switch` is used to shift
groups.  This turned out to be wrong, however.  According to the
[Wikipedia page on the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key), “AltGr” seems to come from
IBM keyboards, and in their manuals it says that it is an abbreviation
for “alternate graphics”.  This makes sense, since it seems likely that
using the keyboard to draw “graphics” (box-drawing characters used in
text user interfaces) came well before there was good support for
switching quickly between multiple scripts.