# xmodmap not working with AltGr and arrow keys

Tags: linux, keyboard, xmodmap

I have an `us altgr-intl` layout.

with this command :

```
>_xmodmap -e "keycode 113 = Left NoSymbol U21BC NoSymbol U21BC U21BC U21BC"
```

(Or just 6 combinations, I tried many things ...)

- <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> still act like <kbd>←</kbd> alone and 
  <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> still act like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>
- <kbd>Mode_shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> works well.

I have some <kbd>Fn</kbd>'s functions related to my arrows.

If I assign the formula above to a key without <kbd>Fn</kbd>'s functions, it will work.

Is it a problem solvable at software level?

Comment: I have had a similar problem. `AltGr` only works after making it `Mode_switch`, like so: `xmodmap -e "keysym Alt_R = Mode_switch Mode_switch Mode_switch"`.

Comment: thx but I am fine with my -layout `us` -variant `AltGr-intl`; and I am just exploring how to use more modifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You cannot extend extend behavior of any key to use AltGr :](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249122/why-do-my-xmodmap-binds-involving-altgr-only-work-on-some-keys#)

Each key have a `type`, and those one are `ONE_LEVEL`.

The solution is to mess with `xkb`.

```
$ xkbcomp  $DISPLAY output.dump
```

will dump your full keymap.

We see here :

```
key <LEFT> { [      Left ] };
```

We can modify it as :

```
    Key <LEFT> {
type[group1]= "FOUR_LEVEL",
type[group2]= "TWO_LEVEL",
symbols[group1]= [      Left,   Left,    Right,   Down],
symbols[group2]= [      Prior,  End ] };
```

There is two `type` handled by two `group` :

'FOUR_LEVEL' is here <kbd>Base</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>

'TWO_LEVEL' is here <kbd>Mode_switch</kbd>, <kbd>Mode_switch</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>

Then test the map :

```
$ xkbcomp output.dump $DISPLAY
```

Everything works ... 
almost ... well,
my Virtual Machines grabs now the default layout instead of mine and,

And I always have a strange behavior with some combinations of <kbd>Fn</kbd>'s key
(I have two of them and one don't accept some modifiers).