# Virtualbox and Manjaro i3 (where is mod key)?

Tags: virtualbox, i3, manjaro

I am using Manjaro with i3 desktop on Virtualbox and I can't seem to figure out what the mod key is (I'm using a standard English keyboard).

- I've done the expected finger mashing and have tried several different combinations to no avail.
- I know the key to release from the Host is the Right-Cntrl key.
- I've read that the Windows (Super) key can be the mod key but this has not seemed to be successful for me. For instance, I've been trying to do `Super+Enter` to open a terminal.

Comment: `mod` is just short for `modifier`.  Ctrl, Alt, Hyper, and Super are all different modifier keys (the Win key is usually treated as Super, and Hyper is unassigned, or vice versa).  does your `i3` config file (probably `/home/username/.config/i3/config`) start with "`set $mod [something]`"?  that [something] is the defined mod key.  post details of your config file if you still need help.

Comment: Hmm, I think the problem is that when I hit my Super key it opens the pop-up menu on my Host machine. I'm new to i3 and I can't figure out how to do anything since everything seems to require the use of the `mod` key (like opening a terminal)...

Comment: @BlazePascal Remap `mod` to alt key in your `i3` configuration file. It should be located at `$HOME/.config/i3/config`. Open it with an editor of your choice and make a necessary edits (i.e. `nano $HOME/.config/i3/config`).

Comment: @ddnomad Is right click supposed to be disabled at default for i3? I can't seem to figure out how to open anything (terminals, file browers, etc.) except the update manager. In the bottom left window there's some instructions to open a terminal (`mod+enter`) but that's the issue at hand. In the bottom right I can click on the update manager, sound, network manager.

Comment: @BlazePascal `i3` works only with shortcuts and the majority of them (actually all of them) require a working $mod key. `$mod+d` launches `dmenu` which is a minimalist text application launcher. Without working $mod key you won't get far.

Comment: @ddnomad I figured out I can do a `cntrl+alt+A` to open the action editor. Do you happen (or anyone else) to know of another way to open a terminal or file browser other than using `mod`? Or maybe I can edit something from Virtualbox's side?

Comment: @BlazePascal personally I doubt there is a way to open anything without $mod key. Remapping Virtualbox keys is a good way to fix this issue. Just make sure Virtualbox doesn't use win key in any way.

Comment: you can use any keybind you like, as long as the keybinds are set properly in the i3 config using the `bindsym` keywords.  see [`man i3`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/i3); default keybinds and a sample config file is shown using `Mod1` ([the `Alt` key](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119219/222377)).  (that's why my first comment asked what your config file defined `$mod` to be -- the `$` indicates that it's a variable.)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I needed to do from the VirtualBox side was go into `File->Preferences->Input` and then uncheck the `"Auto-Capture Keyboard"` button.

And then I can do `$mod+enter` to get the terminal (and all other functionality working.

Comment: default `i3` mapping sets $mod to either win/super or alt key. What do you mean by `Windows/Super+$mod+enter`? Do you mean just `$mod+enter`?