# Why Tab can't be modified with ISO_Level3_Shift

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xkb, xmodmap

I am using a 40 key keyboard called daisy, I want to have a consistent layout of all my keyboards. The tab can't modified to other keys is kind a waste of resources.

The relevant part in .Xmodmap is:

```
clear Mod5
! 47 is the ; key on the keyboard
keycode 47 = ISO_Level3_Shift ISO_Level3_Shift ISO_Level3_Shift ISO_Level3_Shift ISO_Level3_Shift ISO_Level3_Shift
add Mod5 = ISO_Level3_Shift
keycode 23 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Next Next Next Next
```

But press ; + Tab is still insert Tab. How to make it Next?

Use xev I get this while pressing ;+tab and shift+tab

```
KeyPress event, serial 10256, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xe5, subw 0x0, time 123115414, (483,707), root:(483,737),
    state 0x0, keycode 47 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 10256, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xe5, subw 0x0, time 123115538, (483,707), root:(483,737),
    state 0x80, keycode 23 (keysym 0xff09, Tab), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (09) " "
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (09) "   "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 10256, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xe5, subw 0x0, time 123115672, (483,707), root:(483,737),
    state 0x80, keycode 23 (keysym 0xff09, Tab), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (09) " "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 10256, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xe5, subw 0x0, time 123115703, (483,707), root:(483,737),
    state 0x80, keycode 47 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 10256, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xe5, subw 0x0, time 123141310, (483,707), root:(483,737),
    state 0x0, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 10256, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xe5, subw 0x0, time 123141590, (483,707), root:(483,737),
    state 0x1, keycode 23 (keysym 0xfe20, ISO_Left_Tab), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 10256, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xe5, subw 0x0, time 123141757, (483,707), root:(483,737),
    state 0x1, keycode 23 (keysym 0xfe20, ISO_Left_Tab), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 10256, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xe5, subw 0x0, time 123141839, (483,707), root:(483,737),
    state 0x1, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: This is why people send warnings about xmodmap. If you have complex layers and do not want to destruct them, use xkb.