# swap symbols with numbers in keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm looking to modify my keyboard layout such that holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and pressing a number key will result in a number being printed to the screen instead of the symbol that's on the key.

For example <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> would print `9`, while <kbd>9</kbd>  will print `(`.

I'd also like to switch "[" and "]" with "{" and "}" respectively, in the same manner.

I suspect the program `setxkbmap` will be useful, but I don't know how to use it for this purpose.

Incidentally, [there exists a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39014/switch-between-numbers-and-symbols-on-caps-lock), but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

I use Linux Mint 16 Mate Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use xev and xmodmap.

Check out the following answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys

About halfway down the answer it addresses using the shift key.

For example, in the case of the 9 key:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 18 = parenleft 9"
```

From the man pages:

keycode NUMBER = KEYSYMNAME ...
               The list of keysyms is assigned to the indicated keycode (which
               may be specified in decimal, hex or octal and can be determined
               by running the xev  program).   Up  to  eight  keysyms  may  be
               attached  to  a  key, however the last four are not used in any
               major X server implementation.  **The first keysym is  used  when
               no  modifier  key  is pressed in conjunction with this key, the
               second with Shift, the third when the Mode_switch key  is  used
               with  this  key  and  the  fourth when both the Mode_switch and
               Shift keys are used.**